Not able to set authorization in hive
I have deployed hive using this docker compose from official hive documentation.
When trying to access admin role by logging in as admin user
docker exec -it hiveserver2 beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10000/' -n hive
and doing set role admin;
I am getting this error
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40000 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask. kaif doesn't belong to role admin


What am i missing here ?
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'metastore_db'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'hive'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - hive-db:/var/lib/postgresql
    networks:
      - hive

  metastore:
    image: apache/hive:4.0.0
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: metastore
    hostname: metastore
    environment:
      DB_DRIVER: postgres
      SERVICE_NAME: 'metastore'
      SERVICE_OPTS: '-Xmx1G -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=org.postgresql.Driver
                     -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/metastore_db
                     -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=hive
                     -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=password'
    ports:
        - '9083:9083'
    volumes:
        - warehouse:/opt/hive/data/warehouse
        - type: bind
          source: /Users/apple/postgresql-42.7.3.jar
          target: /opt/hive/lib/postgres.jar
    networks:
      - hive

  hiveserver2:
    image: apache/hive:kaif
    depends_on:
      - metastore
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: hiveserver2
    environment:
      HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT: 10000
      SERVICE_OPTS: '-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://metastore:9083
                    -Dhive.users.in.admin.role=hive
                    -Dhive.security.metastore.authorization.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.MetaStoreAuthzAPIAuthorizerEmbedOnly
                    -Dhive.security.authorization.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory
                    -Dhive.security.authorization.enabled=true'
      IS_RESUME: 'true'
      SERVICE_NAME: 'hiveserver2'
    ports:
      - '10000:10000'
      - '10002:10002'
    volumes:
      - warehouse:/opt/hive/data/warehouse
    networks:
      - hive

volumes:
  hive-db:
  warehouse:

networks:
  hive:
    name: hive

I am following instructions from here
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization
